# Perform both multiplication and addition in parallel using cuda

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, dot-product

I have two vectors and I want to calculate dot product of those two vectors in parallel. I was able to do multiplication of each element in parallel and after that addition in parallel. following is the code which I have tried.

But I want to do **both multiplication and addition in parallel**. That means elements which have performed multiplication should be added even if other elements haven't done multiplication yet. Hope you understood what I have said.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
__global__ void dotproduct(int *a,int *b,int *c,int N)
{
    int k=N;
    int i=threadIdx.x;                      
    c[i]=a[i]*b[i];                         
    if(N%2==1)                          
        N=N+1;                          
    __syncthreads();                        
    while(i<(N/2))
    {
        if((i+1)*2<=k)
        {
            c[i]=c[i*2]+c[i*2+1];               
        }
        else
        {
            c[i]=c[k-1];
        }
        k=N/2;
        N=N/2;
        if(N%2==1&&N!=1)                            
            N=N+1;
        __syncthreads();                    //wait for all the threads to synchronize               
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N=10;                           //vector size
    int a[N],b[N],c[N];                     
    int *dev_a,*dev_b,*dev_c;                   
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a,N*sizeof(int));           
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b,N*sizeof(int));           
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c,N*sizeof(int));           
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        a[i]=rand()%10;                     
        b[i]=rand()%10;                     
    }
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a,a,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b,b,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   
    dotproduct<<<1,N>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c,N);           
    cudaMemcpy(c,dev_c,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);   
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d,%d\n",a[i],b[i]);                

    }
    printf("the answer is : %d in GPU\n",c[0]);         

    cudaFree(dev_a);                        
    cudaFree(dev_b);                        
    cudaFree(dev_c);                        
    cudaThreadExit();                       
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes sense to do multiplication and addition in parallel - all multiplications will take the same time, and by trying to run different instructions at the same time can reduce the performance. But the part in which you sum the multiplication results can be optimized.

You many need to use atomics or shuffle instructions - read this for a good explanation: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/

And if it's not an exercise but a real task, I suggest you use cuBLAS, it has this functionality build in: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-dot

Answer (score 0):

Take your favorite reduction (= adding-up of the values of a vector), and modify it so that instead of every read from the single input vector, you perform two reads, with the same index, from two input vectors, and multiply the results.

This will maintain as much parallelism as you were able to effect using the reduction kernel; and if your reads were memory-coalesced before, they will also be coalesced now. Your throughput in terms of output elements per time unit should be almost exactly half what it was before, for very long vectors.

Comment: could you please make changes to the code as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I could. But so could you. Also, your code performs dot-product between multiple pairs of vectors - one per thread block - and is problematic for large values of N.

Answer (score -1):

I think that there is also a special PTX ISA instruction which does dot-product at once ( dp4a.atype.btype  d, a, b, c; ). With little effort you can try to write a small inline PTX assembly function. Check the documentation.